# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: MyClass

Tags: android, android-studio

This is driving me insane.  Using Android Studio 4.0.2, and I keep getting this exception when running in the emulator.

My store releases are fine, and if I do a clean rebuild it sorts out the problem and the Android app runs in the debuggger.  As soon as I change a line of code, it's back again, and I need to rebuild again to clear the problem.

I don't understand how my app in the store release can be fine, and how it works fine when I do a rebuild, but something gets corrupt when I change code.

I have done a clean install of Windows, a clean install of Android Studio and it's exactly the same.  Is anyone else seeing this problem?

It seemed to be when I brought in the Volley library, but I could be wrong on that.   I know it hasn't always done this.

If it is volley, I am using the latest version:

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

My app targets SDK30

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe enabling MultiDex would help: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Also, you should post the whole error stacktrace that you're getting.